# linq where clause not producing expected results

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml:

```
<Root>
    <Result img="1.png" name="a">
        <Programs>
            <Program name="foo1">
                <ProgramID>1</ProgramID>
            </Program>
        </Programs>
    </Result>
    <Result img="2.png" name="b">
        <Programs>
            <Program name="foo1">
                <ProgramID>1</ProgramID>
            </Program>
            <Program name="foo2">
                <ProgramID>2</ProgramID>
            </Program>
        </Programs>
    </Result>
    <Result img="3.png" name="c">
        <Programs>
              <Program name="foo1">
                <ProgramID>1</ProgramID>
            </Program>
        </Programs>
    </Result>
    <Result img="4.png" name="d">
        <Programs>
             <Program name="foo1">
                <ProgramID>1</ProgramID>
            </Program>
        </Programs>
    </Result>
</Root>
```

I am trying to filter xml by ProgramID with below linq statement but i always get no results back when i pass a value of 2, strangely when i pass a value of 1 in I do get expected results back which is all four results.

```
xOut = New XElement("Root", _
                                   From s In x...<Result> _
                                   Where s.<Programs>.<Program>.<ProgramID>.Value = 2 _
                                   Select s)
```

What is wrong with linq query.  Why does a 1 work but a 2 does not?  I would also like xml structure preserved after filtering.

Comment: It's not strange, your XML is malformed. Under `<Result img="2.png" name="b">` you have two `Program` items, the rest have only one. You would need a way to query this collection of `Program`s.

Comment: The XML is not malformed - those `Program` nodes are under a parent `Programs` node which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it in C#:

```
        var xOut = new XElement(
            "Root",
            x.Descendants("Result")
            .Where(y => y.Descendants("Programs").Descendants("Program").Descendants("ProgramID")
            .Any(z => z.Value == "2")));
```

Not sure what the VB.NET equivalent would be though, sorry.

Comment: Thank you Jesse C. Slicer, your code worked perfectly.  I think the "Any" function was the key here.  Here's the code in vb if anyone is interested:

>xOut = New XElement("Root", _
> x.Descendants("Result").Where _
> (Function(y) y.<Programs>.<Program>.<ProgramID>.Any(Function(z) z.Value = "2")))